# Translating "if I had to" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

Consider this translation:

> I would have jumped the rope.
>
> Hubiese saltado a la cuerda.

Now, how would we translate the same sentence if I added "if I had to" to it?

> I would have jumped the rope if I had to.

Comment: It's not *hubiese*, but *habría*. The subjunctive goes in the "si..." part, and the conditional in the other one.

Comment: "Si tuviera que..." would also work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is wrong to begin with.

> I would have jumped the rope.
>
> Hubiese saltado la cuerda.

`Hubiese saltado la cuerda` translats to `Had I jumped the rope`

The correct translation would be

> I would have jumped the rope.
>
> Habría saltado la cuerda.

Here is how I would say it:

> Si tuviera que saltarla, habría saltado la cuerda
>
> Si tuviera que saltar la cuerda, la habría saltado

If you use haber, like in this sentence

> Si hubiese tenido que hacerlo, habría saltado la cuerda

It will translate to:

> If I **had had** to do it, I would have jumped the rope.

---

Hubiese and Hubiera are the same thing, by the way.

If you want to say, `I would have done it`, you would say

`Lo habría hecho`

When you start writing conditional statements, with a cause, and reason.. you get sentences like this

`If I had an apple, then I would eat it`

`Si yo tuviera una manzana la comería`

It boils down to this guideline

`If... something in the subjunctive.. then... something in the conditional..`

or

`Something in the conditional, then.. something subjunctive.`

example

`Yo habría saltado la cuerda si yo tuviera que hacerlo.`

Comment: *Si tuviera que saltarla la habría saltado a la cuerda* is wrong. And so is your next sentence, which has two mistakes less than the former. But I also had that mistake because I Ctrl+V-ed from the OP. Namely, one doesn't say *a la cuerda* but *la cuerda*.

Comment: Moreover, I don't know in English, but in Spanish that combination of tenses sounds strange.

Comment: If the only reason you say that I'm wrong is because I said `saltar a`, then the OP is wrong... The question was about the use of past subjunctive, but was using it incorrectly.  He was using the subjunctive when he should have used the conditional tense.

Comment: OK, this leaves me thoroughly confused. "A la cuerda" or just "la cuerda"? "Hubiese" or "habría"? How about just skipping the "haber" and use "tuviese" instead? What would be the difference in the meanings?

Comment: Yeap, the OP is wrong. But I downvoted because of the object (*la*) repetition; and there's no comma.

Answer (score 3):

It's not answering the question you posed but it's what you want to know:

> Hubiese saltado la cuerda si hubiese tenido que (hacerlo).

The omission of the last verb is advanced. Or

> Si hubiese tenido que hacerlo, hubiese saltado la cuerda.

Comment: Instead of "...hubiese tenido que...", can't one just say, "...tuviese que..."?

Comment: Can I use "pudiese" if I want to say "...if I could"? Sorry if the question seems a tad off-track.

Comment: @c.p.
`Si hubiese tenido que hacerlo, hubiese saltado la cuerda.`
would mean..
`If I had had to do it, had jumped the rope.`

Comment: @dockeryz You're right.

Comment: "Si hubiese tenido que hacerlo, *habría* saltado la cuerda"

Answer (score 3):

The correct phrase is:

> Habría saltado la cuerda si hubiera tenido que hacerlo.

Correct, but slightly clumsy. Some alternatives:

> Si hubiera tenido que saltar la cuerda, lo habría hecho.
>
> Habría saltado la cuerda en caso de haber tenido que hacerlo.
>
> Habría saltado la cuerda de ser necesario.
>
> Habría saltado la cuerda de haberme visto obligado a ello.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Saltar a la cuerda" or "saltar la cuerda"?  This varies by region.  But that's not what you were asking about....
2. For clarity about *hubiera*, *hubiese* and *habría*, please see this excellent and concise post: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20738/9385.

Now, what you were actually asking:

> How would this be expressed in Spanish? "I would have jumped the rope if I had to."

I'm going to modify your question a little bit because "jumped the rope" is awkward for me to work with.  First, because I would say, "I would have jump-roped" (and that might veer us off to *what exactly is the past participle of "to jump rope") and second, because it's hard for me to imagine someone being *required* to jump rope.

> I would have gone to the bank yesterday (to make a deposit) if I had to [but it wasn't necessary because my automatic paycheck deposit came through in time].

A literal translation would be

> Hubiera ido al banco ayer (para hacer un depósito) si hubiera tenido que hacerlo.

In place of the first *hubiera*, *hubiese* and *habría* are also possible.  In place of the second, *hubiese* is also possible. (See the previously cited https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20738/9385.)

A little bit more natural would be

> Habría ido al banco ayer si hubiera sido necesario.

or

> Habría ido al banco ayer si hubiera tenido que hacerlo.

But the natural, idiomatic way to express this is:

> **Hubiera ido al banco ayer de ser necesario.**

Let's back-translate, to make sure you understand what this means:

> *I would have gone to the bank yesterday if it had been necessary.*

Answer (score -1):

*If I had to* cook -> *Si yo tuviera que* cocinar.

*Si tuviera que cocinar* is less accurate.

Comment: Isn't it common for native speakers to omit the subject in regular conversations?

Comment: tuviera or tuviese?

Comment: Tuviera and tuviese are exactly the same. If you look at any conjugation table, you'll see that it always says "tuviera o tuviese" (or so it should). For example, [this one](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=MzNJDzVaXVcRjF4tlkxT)

Comment: @AmitSchandillia, yep, it's quite common. I'm a Spanish native speaker.

Comment: @TheLearner - "Isn't it common for native speakers to omit the subject in regular conversations?" Yes.