# Do Spanish natives prefer using "hubiera" instad of "había", even if the subjunctive is not necessary?

Tags: subjuntivo

I have seen this phrase and I wondered if it was correct:
"Juro que él hubiera sido el primer fan" but to me, this was grammatically incorrect as the verb "jurar" does not require the subjunctive. Or am I wrong? I also thought this might be because natives prefer "hubiera" instead of "había", but again this is only a guess of mine and needs confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: This is actually substituting subjunctive for conditional. There have been a number of questions dealing with that; see for example [this one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/habr%c3%ada-hecho-vs-hubiera-hecho). If that answers your question, I think we could close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Habría hecho vs hubiera hecho](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/habr%c3%ada-hecho-vs-hubiera-hecho)

Comment: doesn't look like a duplicate, 
in this case it seems like the OP is having confusion between the imperfect past and the subjuntive form of the imperfect past

Comment: Hi there. I do know the difference between the two however in this sentence it seemed to me that there is no need for the pluperfect subjunctive as the sentence does not conclude with a condition (si clause). That is why I was asking this question - I thought this is another one of the ways natives disregard grammatical rules however are still understood by others around them.

Comment: Andreea, where have you seen this?  It looks weird to me too.

Comment: It's not the same meaning, are two absolutly different phrases, a verb does not require/not require a subjuntive, is just another mode of reality and possibility. Conditional is very different that subjuntive, but people uses as the same thing by missconcepting.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence:

"Juro que él hubiera sido el primer fan"

is correct if a condition is implied, and if "jurar" is used to express present certainty rather than certainty about a past event:

1. Juro que él hubiera sido el primer fan si la hubiera conocido. (The speaker claims that, if he had met/known her, he would have been her number one fan, but he didn't.)

In a context in which the condition is implicit, the sentence proposed would be perfect to refer to a past hypothetical scenario:

1'. Es una pena que Bob no haya conocido a Whitney Houston. Juro que (de haberla conocido) hubiera sido el primer fan.

The indicative would be used to refer to a real past event:

2. Juro que él había sido el primer fan. (I assure you he had been her first fan at the time.)

Note: To clarify the meaning of "jurar" as requested by @aparente001 in a comment, my understanding is that in sentence (1) the speaker expresses a present belief **about a hypothetical event that never occurred**: "Hubiera sido el primer fan, estoy seguro" (He would have been the first fan, I'm sure). Instead, in sentence (2) the verb "jurar" is used **to ratify something that actually happened**: "Te aseguro que había sido el primer fan" (I assure you he had been the first fan).

Comment: would this this be a better answer if you add that this is a the subjuntive of imperfect presente ?  and thus it is used as the way you explained ?

Comment: Hi Gustavon. Thanks for this clarification. It confirmed what I was thinking. The sentence does not imply a condition and simply concludes with "Juro que él hubiera sido el primer fan de ellos", which is grammatically incorrect, right, since the speaker is referring to a real past event (which triggers the indicative), and also the sentence, as I mentioned does not end with a condition. If it did, I am aware that "habría" would be the correct alternative, or even "hubiera" as I see many natives employing today. "Hubiese" is used as the first verb in the clause to avoid cacophony.

Comment: No, the sentence is correct as is. I will expand my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh right, now I understand it fully. Thanks so much for your help, Mr Gustavson!

Comment: I don't understand "if "jurar" is used to express present certainty rather than certainty about a past event" -- is there perhaps a typo?  Do you mean "if "jurar" is used to express present uncertainty rather than certainty about a past event"?  Granted, that's a little weird, for "jurar" to express uncertainty, but it would explain  the "hubiera."  On the other hand, if there's no typo, then could you edit that sentence a bit to make it clearer?  Thanks.